# How to create background service for repeated execution of location tracker in ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, memory-management, background

- I am getting continuous location coordinates from GPS tracking device through web service.
- I am plotting retrieved coordinates using MKPointAnnotation continuously with the Interval of 10.0 seconds.
- I have applied GCD while parsing.
  so that parsing will be in background and UI Update will be in main thread 
  as follows

  > dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(
  >   DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void)
  >                                       {
  >                                           //Background Thread
  >
  > ```
  >                                      //1# Get Location Coordinates [PARSING PART]
  >                                     NSArray *coordinateArray = geometryDictio[@"coordinates"];
  >
  >
  >                                     NSString *latitude = [coordinateArray objectAtIndex:1];
  >                                     NSString *longitude = [coordinateArray objectAtIndex:0];
  >
  >                                     double latitudeDouble = [latitude doubleValue];
  >                                     double longitudeDouble = [longitude doubleValue];
  >
  >
  >
  >                                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
  >                                     {
  >                                         //Run UI Updates
  >
  >                                         //1# Get Location Coordinates [UI PART]
  >                                         // Remove
  >                                         [self removeAnnotation];
  >                                         // Add new
  >                                         [self plotPoint:latitudeDouble :longitudeDouble];
  >
  >
  >                                     });
  >
  >                                     });
  > ```
- after that I applied 10.0 second Timer to above part and executed that in viewDidLoad as follows

> ```
> [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(handleTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
> ```

- I have also cleared all unused variables
- Everything is working fine in App , I am getting accurate cooordinates and plotting successfully on map.
- Timer also working properly

**- But the problem is App is getting slow after some time . If I am running continuously for 1-2 hour.**

> - Please suggest mememory optimization techniques
> - please suggest any alternative to call Timer other than viewdidload
> - please suggest any flexible way to deallocate variables after some time  [as ARC cleared memory after Default time]
> - Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you can set varibables as nil

Comment: In any other life cycle method or in same method where I am performing Parsing

Comment: You can set as nil into viewwilldisappear method, though it's not appropriate thing to do bcause ARC forbids for releasing variables,

Comment: Use the time profiler instrument to determine where your app is spending time.